# Divisibility of $\sigma (n) $

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if n is a positive integer such that $24|(n + 1)$, then $24| \sigma(n)$

I had 2 attempts at this, but neither resulted in a complete argument.
 One of the closer attempts used the fact that $\sigma (n) = d_1 +d_2 +\cdots+d_k $ then I wrote that each number could be paired with its multiple that makes n, ie.

$\sigma (n) = d_1(\frac{n}{d_1} +d_2 (\frac{n}{d_2}) +... $
We know there is a even number of these since $n \equiv -1 $ mod 24, but after that I got stuck...

Comment: $\sigma (23) $ is the sum of all divisors of 23 since its prime that is just 23+1 =24 hence 24 divided it in this case. @Joffan

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103379/showing-24n1-implies24-sigman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea is basically sound. One has $n\equiv-1\pmod{24}$. Any
factor of $n$ is coprime to $6$ and one can check all possibilities
modulo $24$ to ensure that $d^2\equiv1\pmod{24}$ and
so $n/d\equiv-d\pmod{24}$ for all $d\mid n$. So pairing off $d$
with $n/d$ gives $\sigma(n)$ as the sum of a bunch of instances
of $d+n/d$ each of which is a multiple of $24$.